# Elementary Analysis_limsup and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Prove that  $limsup|S_n|^{1/n}$ $\le$ $limsup|S_{n+1}/S_n|$

Let $a$ = $limsup|S_n|^{1/n}$ and $L$ = $limsup|S_{n+1}/S_n|$

To prove that $a$ $\le$ $L$ it would suffice to show that

$a$ $\le$ $L_1$ for any $L_1$ > $L$

I am confused about the last part since if

$a$ = $L_1$ then $a$ would be larger than $L$

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but I noticed that you got answers for several of your other questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't aware of it. Will make sure to accept from now on